# issue when using assembly plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

when I use

```
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                **<version>2.3</version>**
                <configuration>
                     <descriptorRefs>
                           <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                     </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

I found when I do not use version tag, I received the totally different jar. Also, some files even duplicate inside jar when I do not specify version.

why?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't give an explicit version in your pom Maven uses the version which is defined by the super pom which comes with the maven version you have installed and that is usually a one which is older and might have problems or might not support the functionality you need. This results in defining all the time a version explicit or use a parent pom which defines the versions of the plugins to have a reproducible build.